# Realtime equalizer for arbitrary playback software using ASIO SDK 2.3 I/O

Tags: c++, audio, real-time, equalizer, steinberg-asio

I want to develop an equalizer that runs in the background and process the incoming audio signal from whichever audio playback software using the asio4all driver in real-time, with a variable buffer size from 64 samples. The goal is to keep latency as low as possible

I've been thinking of ways to implement this equalizer. How should it takes the incoming stream of an arbitrary playback software(knowing it use asio4all of source) is not clear to me.

My coding template is [hostsample.cpp] in the asio SDK but maybe it's not enough. I haven't explored other sample in Asio SDK yet.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to compile the example in the SDK _as-is_ and run it in Cubase? If so, finding out where it gets its input and where it puts it output _should_ not be hard. I guess I don''t understand what the real issue is.

Comment: As for implementing an EQ, I think I'd start with a FFT iibrary (iike fftw).

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes the host example is able to run, but only predefined signal. I have no problem with the output to interface part but I have no idea how to handle taking input from other processes

Comment: Ok, it was 15-20 years ago for me so I don't remember. Have you tried the [asio forum @ 
sdk.steinberg.net](https://sdk.steinberg.net/viewforum.php?f=1)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo not yet, I'm not sure how active that forum is, might worth trying though. Thanks!